# Is it possible to to communicate an iOS app communicate over the USB port to a Windows computer?

Tags: ios, xcode, windows, usb, tcp

I have an iOS application with a tableview which I would like to send text strings via USB to my Windows computer indicating which cell was selected by the user.Anyone have experience with this type of interface?

Answer (score 1):

I've written a blog post detailing how to achieve this here.

http://thecodewash.blogspot.com/2017/05/communicating-with-your-ios-app-over.html

To answer your question (so this answer isn't just a link), yes it definitely is possible to achieve this utilizing the USB Multiplexing Daemon (usbmuxd) program that is usually installed as part of iTunes. This program can create a socket connection to your iOS device through the USB cable, and allow you to communicate via that socket connection like you would any other socket. The link goes into much more detail.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

(In short) Yes, you can communicate with ios application via normal socket communication by using ITunes which acts like proxy. In this model your ios app acts like server listening for connection. Windows app must connect to iTunes on port 27015 and estabilish connection to specific port (used by ios app) on connected via usb device. This is done by using a special MUX protocol described [here](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Usbmux)